# ¿Es posible declarar una variable JavaScript dinámicamente?

Tags: javascript, ajax, variables

Tengo una función JavaScript para crear el objeto `persona`:

```js
function persona(altura, peso) {
  this.altura = altura;
  this.peso = peso;
}

const persona1 = new persona("165 Cm.", "70 Kg.");
```

No se me ocurre cómo reemplazar `persona1` con un nombre obtenido mediante **Ajax** de una base de datos para que la constante sea:

```js
const Juan = new persona("165 Cm.","70 Kg.");
```

Y así poder crear tantas constantes de persona con su nombre, como nombres tenga en la base de datos.

Si alguien sabe o se le ocurre me ayudaría muchísimo.

El nombre de la persona que obtengo mediante **Ajax** lo almaceno en una variable:

```js
var nombre = response;
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el objetivo?, no puedes declarar `const..` dinámicas, `ajax` ya debería devolverte en `JSON` con ello no tiene sentido reinstaciarlos como `new Per...`, talvez puedas crear una `Clase` y usarlo `this[res.nombre] = {}`

Comment: Hola! El objetivo es crear un nuevo objeto con un nombre de la base de datos sin recargar la página.
No uso JSON, el nuevo nombre lo recibo en JavaScript mediante AJAX y un "echo" realizado por una página PHP.

Comment: Si no usas `JSON`, entonces estarás usando `XML` supongo, ¿estás seguro de eso? hace mucho que no se utiliza eso. Por otro lado, ¿para qué tener una variables con el nombre de la persona (además de que pueden existir colisiones), porqué no simplemente mantener un array con los valores?

Comment: Utilicé el ejemplo de persona y su nombre para simplificar.
Lo que haré ahora es crear una nueva pregunta con parte del código para que se entienda perfectamente.
Estoy usando para recibir el nombre AJAX y PHP.
La variable contiene números de ID, no hay posiblidad de colisión.

Comment: Los valores, en este caso ID, se crean dinámicamente junto a datos aleatorios y es imposible pre-cargarlos.
Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar `window`, de manera que añades nuevos elementos a la ventana actual para definir variables, puedes obtenerlas usando el mismo nombre definido o en su lugar referirte a ella con `window`, ya que será una propiedad de esta

```js
window["var1"] = "Hello world";
console.log(var1);
console.log(window["var1"]);
```

Esta será una variable global, no puedes obtener con este método las constantes ni las variables definidas con `let` ya que este da alcance de bloque y la variable no será obtenible fuera del *scope* del script que la define

---

Puedes también hacerlo con `eval` y funciona de la misma manera, pero como dice en la [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/eval/#:%7E:text=eval()%20es%20generalmente%20tambi%C3%A9n%20m%C3%A1s%20lenta%20que%20otras%20alternativas%20desde%20que%20se%20invoca%20en%20el%20int%C3%A9rprte%20de%20JS,%20mientras%20que%20otros%20muchos%20constructores%20son%20optimizados%20por%20los%20motores%20JS%20modernos.)

> eval() es generalmente también más lenta que otras alternativas desde que se invoca en el intérprete de JS, mientras que otros muchos constructores son optimizados por los motores JS modernos.

Además de referencias de [SitePoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/call-javascript-function-string-without-using-eval/#:%7E:text=This%20feature%20is%20obsolete.,a%20string%20containing%20code%2C%20e.g.)

> Esta característica está obsoleta. Aunque todavía es compatible con los navegadores, se desaconseja su uso en nuevos proyectos. Trate de evitar su uso.

*Traducido al español, la traducción es propia*

Puedes hacerlo así

```js
eval(`var nombreVariable = "valor"`);
console.log(nombreVariable);
```

Esta función, ejecuta código desde un *String* y puede ser de riesgo si no se usa adecuadamente.

---

Por último, como una alternativa, puedes hacer una función y ejecutarla con `new Function`

```js
new Function(`var persona1 = "John doe"; console.log(persona1);`)();
```

---

Como sabrás, el nombre de una variable tiene las siguientes reglas:

- No contiene espacios
- No empieza con números
- No empieza con signos especiales

Has puesto una variable *Hello World* y no es válida

```js
window["Hello world"] = "abc";
alert(Hello world);
```

Si usas el último método (con funciones), la variable será válida únicamente para la función.

**Aquí hay un ejemplo** simulando obtener un objeto con **AJAX**

```js
const response = [{"name":"John"},{"name":"Doe"}];

response.forEach(el => {
  window["Name"+el.name] = el.name;
});

console.log(NameJohn);
console.log(NameDoe);
console.log(window["NameJohn"]);
console.log(window["NameDoe"]);
```

Obtenemos un array de objetos, lo recorremos con *forEach* y añadimos una variable en la ventana actual por cada nombre, finalmente la imprimimos

Comment: Gracias. Probaré y luego respondo.

Comment: Mi problema original persiste. No puedo utilizar:
alert(Hello World.nombre);
Saludos y gracias!

Answer (score 0):

eso lo podrias hacer con eval, aqui un ejemplo del uso de eval

```
var strvar = "var z = 5;";

 function evalvar()
 {
    eval(strvar);
    alert(z * 3);
 }
```

Comment: Wow, voy a probar y luego respondo.

Comment: Aguas con `eval`, XSS en 3, 2, 1...

Comment: [No se recomienda para nada usar `eval` casi bajo ningún motivo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/eval#no_utilice_eval_innecesariamente). Saludos